# Input radio buttons set state of boolean value incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, input, radio-button, setstate

I have two radios buttons for setting the 'urgency' attribute that is a boolean on the database. I tried setting the states manually because for some reason React keep changing the booleans to strings. This is my code:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     urgency: false
   };

  this.radioHandler = this.radioHandler.bind(this);
  }

  radioHandler (e) {
    console.log(this.state.urgency);
    if(e.target.value === "si"){
      this.setState({
        urgency : true
      })
    }
    else if(e.target.value === "no"){
      this.setState({
        urgency : false
     })
    }
    console.log(this.state.urgency);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>       
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="urgency">Urgencia</Label>
              <div>
                <CustomInput type="radio" id="urgency1" name="urgency" label="Si" value="si" checked={this.state.urgency === true}  inline onChange={this.radioHandler}/>
                <CustomInput type="radio" id="urgency2" name="urgency" label="No" value="no" checked={this.state.urgency === false} inline onChange={this.radioHandler}/>
              </div>
            </FormGroup>
         </Form>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

I set 'urgency' : false as a default value on the constructor. The weird thing is if the value="si" the this.state.urgency print and set the state to 'false'  and if the value="no" this.state.urgency print and set the state to 'true' and both console.log print the same even when there is a setState in between.

I'm really confused, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. If you check the value of `this.state` immediately after calling `setState` you will get the old value rather than the new one. If you need to do something after the state update is completed, you can pass a second argument to `setState` for a callback. You can read more about the way `setState` works in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: ooh, thank you, I knew it has to do something with the asynchronicity of react and the components but I didn't know you have to use a callback to check the result of a setState

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log(this.state.urgency) is getting the old value because setState() is asynchronous unlike this.state = {...} which is synchronous and i think where the confusion comes from.

setState() will be put in the event queue of the component and called sometime in the future, but always after the function its called in has been completed. You can however force some code to be executed upon completion of the function via setState({...}, function() {...}).

The output you're expecting will be produced if you change to the following:

```
radioHandler (e) {
    console.log(this.state.urgency);
    if(e.target.value === "si"){
      this.setState({
        urgency : true
      }, function() { console.log(this.state.urgency); })
    }
    else if(e.target.value === "no"){
      this.setState({
        urgency : false
      }, function() { console.log(this.state.urgency); })
    }
}
```